# What happen to the LM ascent stage

Tags: orbital-mechanics

What happen to the LM Ascent stage after it was jettison   I see from the timeline it was while still orbiting the moon. Did it's orbit decay and it crashed onto the moon??

Comment: The mass concentrations of the moon have influence on the orbits of moon satellites. There are some stable orbits, but most orbits are instable and the end is a crash on the moon surface.